# How can I draw this shape?

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I can't draw this image shape. I tried this xml but it is not same.

**My xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="70dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:right="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

[image: this image:]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define separately the radius for each corner, for example ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="50dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="70dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="50dp"
        android:topRightRadius="70dp" />
</shape>
```